# No OpenCL platforms found?

Tags: diablominer, gpu-mining, miner-configuration

Is it possible to mine with Nvidia Quadro 600? Both GUIMiner and DiabloMiner report that no OpenCL platforms/devices were found. How can I check if GPU has OpenCL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NVidia cards require that you install the [CUDA drivers](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) in addition to the standard video card drivers (ATI/AMD cards ship with OpenCL as part of their driver package). Without these drivers installed they will not be available to any miners.

Since the Quadro 600 appears on the list of [CUDA compatible GPUs](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) it should be mineable, though what kind of performance you'll get is questionable.

Comment: Yup, you're correct. I downloaded "developer drivers" (not the complete toolkit) and it works.